# Definition of "Niche Complementarity"

Tags: ecology, terminology, speciation, community-ecology

What does "Niche Complementarity" mean?

---

On [this](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Niche%20complementarity) website they define "Niche Complementarity" as:

> The tendency for coexisting species which occupy a similar position along one niche dimension

I don't quite understand this definition. The tendency to do what?

---

Notes:

- I know what is an ecological niche and therefore what is a niche dimension. There is no need to define this.
- I am particularly interested in the use of this concept in speciation and adaptive radiation.

Comment: There's more to the definition, it's less clear because of the inserted e.g.'s. The definition is: "The tendency for coexisting species which occupy a similar position along one niche dimension to differ along another;" I took out the examples of altitude and diet.

Comment: @A.Kennard I still donn't get how you manage to read the whole definition but anyway, the important thing is that I now understand the concept of "niche complementarity"! Thank you. You can make an answer out of your comment if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been said by @A.kennard in the comments, the definition the OP found is not complete. The full definition on the link he gave ([here](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-Niche%20complementarity)) is:

Niche Complementarity:

> The tendency for coexisting species which occupy a similar position along one niche dimension to differ along another.

The concept that two competing species will tend to evolve different evological niche is called character displacement. The definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_displacement) is

> Character displacement is the phenomenon where differences among similar species whose distributions overlap geographically are accentuated in regions where the species co-occur, but are minimized or lost where the species’ distributions do not overlap.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good discussion of this in [Chesson & Kuang](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v456/n7219/full/nature07248.html) *Nature* 2008, they propose a way to measure niche complementarity accounting for competition and predation.

Answer (score 0):

Niche complementarity: If the competitor species overlap for one resource dimension then they will differ for another resource dimension. E.g; All the plant species pollinated by humming birds flower at different time of the year.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please add some references to your answer.